# Using statements for DBContext in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4.5 with Entity Framework and everything I'm reading says my database context should be enclosed in a using statement to prevent memory leaks.  However, when I pass my model to my view I lose the ability to join to other tables.

So if I have a model that has:

```
public class people
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public sting name { get; set; }
   public virtual stuff things { get; set; }
}
public class stuff
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public int thingType { get; set; }
}
```

But if in my view I want to to loop add grab all of a persons's stuff I can't if I created my context in a using statement.  What's the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the children while the context is still open. You can do it eagerly or lazily:

```
using (var context = new SomeContext()) {
    // This will do a JOIN on the SQL query,
    // which will bring everything in at once.
    var thePerson = context.people.Include("things").Single(p => p.id == 4);
}

using (var context = new SomeContext()) {
    // This will fire two queries but will retrieve
    // the same data as the previous example
    var thePerson = context.people.Single(p => p.id == 4);
    var theStuff = thePerson.things.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Fantastic.  This is exactly what I was missing.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should call `ToList()` on the child collections when setting the ViewModel inside the `using` block to fetch the child relations before disposing the context.

Comment: I don't think `ToList()` will fetch the children automatically - wouldn't you have to explicitly ask for them either eagerly with an `.Include()`, or lazily by calling the property while the context is still alive? I could be wrong with code first, but with database-first, you only get what you ask for.

Comment: I also am confident that ToList() will not fetch the child relations alone.  They need to be explicitly retrieved before the context is disposed.

Comment: @Steve: I meant on the child collection.  Clarified.